# Homebrew multi user setup

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I was trying to fix my Homebrew installation for multiple users and found a [guide on strug.de](http://web.archive.org/web/20160327060143/http://blog.strug.de/2012/06/my-homebrew-multi-user-setup/), which aims to solve exactly this issue.

I created a `brew` user group, added both of my users in that group and ran this to adjust the permissions:

```
sudo chgrp -R brew /usr/local
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local
sudo chgrp -R brew /Library/Caches/Homebrew
sudo chmod -R g+w /Library/Caches/Homebrew
sudo chgrp -R brew /opt/homebrew-cask
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/homebrew-cask
```

Let's assume I did this while logged into user account **A**. A few days later I'm logged into user account **B** and try to install Dropbox via Cask. That works like a charm, since we fixed the permissions earlier so the brew group is allowed to write in those folders as well.

Now another few days later, I am back logged into account **A** and want to get rid of Dropbox. I run the following command but stuck with the permission error:

```
$ brew cask install dropbox --force
==> Downloading https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=mac&full=1
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/dropbox-latest
==> Symlinking App 'Dropbox.app' to '/Users/friedmann/Applications/Dropbox.app'
Error: Permission denied - /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/dropbox/.metadata/latest/20150217070443.598

  Most likely, this means you have an outdated version of homebrew-cask. Please run:

      brew update && brew upgrade brew-cask && brew cleanup && brew cask cleanup

  If this doesn’t fix the problem, please report this bug:

      https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir'
[...]
```

To fix this for the user **B**, I have to run the `chgrp`'s and `chmod`'s (as stated above) again. However this workaround is not really appreciated, since I don't want to "randomly" run all the commands whenever I switch back and forth between my user accounts.

Is there anything that I am missing or that I did wrong acccording to the guide?

I'm not sure how the author of the guide solved this.

Comment: Just found [brewdo](https://www.zigg.com/code/brewdo/) - a combination of sudo and brew. However it is too "hacky" for my liking. I use [bork](https://github.com/mattly/bork) (a neat DSL), to manage my brew formulas and unfortunately brewdo is not supported there either.

Comment: The website you're linking is a dead link in 2020.

Answer (score 18):

I pieced the following together from a few posts, as I couldn't find everything needed in one place, such as a command for creating the group.

Works for me on macOS Mojave 10.14.4 (18E226).

**brew-multiuser.sh**:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Create a new group, brew
sudo dseditgroup -o create brew

# Change owner to brew group on brew assets
sudo chgrp -R brew $(brew --prefix)/*

# Change permissions to brew group
sudo chmod -R g+w $(brew --prefix)/*

# Add a user to the brew group
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a userOne -t user brew

# Add another user to the brew group
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a userTwo -t user brew

# Validate links, etc.
brew doctor

# Make any corrections from the `brew doctor` warnings, such as relinking.

# Run brew doctor to validate fixes
brew doctor

# Make sure it's working without error, with an update
brew update
```

Comment: You'll want to start a new shell between adding yourself to the brew group and running `brew doctor`, so that your groups update.

Comment: This post deserve more bumps! Thank you so much. In my case, after the above steps, I had to empty the Casks directory for the permissions to work.

Answer (score 6):

Had to do this for my setup on **Catalina 10.15.2** and followed these steps:

> ### Note
>
> I used the Users & Groups settings in System Preferences to make the
>   brew group (choose group when making a new account). I added the
>   execute permission to the group so that I could access a dart2native
>   executable as the non-admin user.
>
> I also used [Cakebrew](https://www.cakebrew.com/) to manage all of the formulae after the
>   configuration was running. I did notice a caveat where if user A has a
>   file locked they will need to run brew cleanup in order to get a clean
>   brew for User B.
>
> When using `brew cask install <appname>` - you may experience issues if one of the users
>   is not an admin and in that case, the admin user may need to do the
>   install.
>
> Other than those caveats everything seems to be working well.

### Setup

*(Assumes Allen is admin and Stan is not)*

- Create a group brew and add both Allen & Stan
- brew doctor (Allen checks if he installed brew correctly)
- sudo chgrp -R brew $(brew --prefix)/* (Change the group of homebrew installation directory)
- sudo chmod -R g+w+x $(brew --prefix)/* (Allow group members to read, write and execute inside this directory)
- brew doctor (Stan checks if he can use homebrew)

(source:https://medium.com/@leifhanack/homebrew-multi-user-setup-e10cb5849d59)

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a little old, but my answer can help others that get here looking for help.

What helped me get over this issue, homebrew-cask for multiple users, was setting up the permissions for the Caskroom folder as well:

```
sudo chgrp -R brew /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom
```

Then `brew cask install dropbox` worked just fine.

Comment: This seems to work for me, but performing `brew update` I only seem to be able to do by the owner for some reason. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, it may be worth adding an update to this answer because they have changed the directories to /usr/local now

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gregorio's answer, I found I must also:

```
sudo chgrp -R brew /usr/local/Cellar
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local/Cellar
```